# Pyspark - compare two data frames removing rows that match exactly, unioning the row w differences, then nulling the values that match

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

So I know how to compare two data frames and removing rows that match using subtraction.  That is fine.

And I know how to union the values that DO NOT match creating a new df with results from both tables that do not match.

What I can't figure out how to do to is then null values that match (and leaving the id col alone) in a distributed fashion using pyspark

Example:

```
df_as_list = [['id','name','monthly_sales'],
              [101,'John Snow', 1234.56],
              [102,'Daenerys Targaryen', 9294.96],
              [103,'Saul Goodman', 1274.57],
              [104,'Bobby Axelrob', 1123459.56],
              [105,'Joe Miller', 34.56],
              [106,'James Holden', 1.23]]
my_schema = df_as_list.pop(0)
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(df_as_list, my_schema)

df_as_list = [['id','name','monthly_sales'],
              [101,'John Snow', 777.56],
              [102,'Daenerys Targaryen', 9294.96],
              [103,'Saul Goodman', 1274.57],
              [104,'Bobby Axelrob', 1123459.56],
              [105,'Joe Miller', 34.56],
              [1106,'James Holden', 1.23]]
my_schema = df_as_list.pop(0)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df_as_list, my_schema)

df1.show()
df2.show()
```

Desired Output:

```
+---+------------------+-------------+
| id|              name|monthly_sales|
+---+------------------+-------------+
|101|                  |      1234.56|
|101|                  |       777.56|
+---+------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: The logic to create your desired output is not clear. Why is id = 101 the only one selected?

Comment: @pault Because its the only row that has a column with values that differ between the two dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to first find the `id`s where there are differences and figure out which columns are equal:

```python
from functools import reduce

diffs = df1.join(df2, on="id")\
    .where(reduce(lambda a, b: a|b, [df1[c] != df2[c] for c in df1.columns]))\
    .select("id", *[(df1[c] == df2[c]).alias(c) for c in df1.columns if c != "id"])
diffs.show()
#+---+----+-------------+
#| id|name|monthly_sales|
#+---+----+-------------+
#|101|true|        false|
#+---+----+-------------+
```

The condition `reduce(lambda a, b: a|b, [df1[c] != df2[c] for c in df1.columns])` will keep only rows where at least one column is different between the two DataFrames.

Now use `diffs` to join to the union of the two DataFrames and use the boolean values to determine if you want to display the column or `null` if they are the same.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col, lit

df1.union(df2).alias("u")\
    .join(diffs.alias("d"), on="id")\
    .select(
        "id", 
        *[
            when(
                col("d."+c), 
                lit(None)
            ).otherwise(col("u."+c)).alias(c) 
            for c in diffs.columns 
            if c != "id"
        ]
    )\
    .show()
#+---+----+-------------+
#| id|name|monthly_sales|
#+---+----+-------------+
#|101|null|       777.56|
#|101|null|      1234.56|
#+---+----+-------------+
```

You will have to put `null` in the matching columns (as opposed to empty string) because the types for the column need to be consistent (unless you cast everything to string).

Comment: OK but the the problem is its not always going to have a "name" column and a "monthly_sales" column.  This is a general example. I want simply to output differences between two dataframes and visually identify where those differences are.

Comment: @timbram but you will always join on `id`? So in other words you want to see the differences between the two dataframes for the same `id`.

Comment: Yes correct. There will always be some Id column though it may not always be called “Id”.

Comment: @timbram updated the answer based on your clarified requirements. You can make the `"id"` column a variable but this is general in that no other column names are hard coded.